# I need a second look at my stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an issue and I do not know if it is with my stored procedure or with the SSRS-like report that looks against the output data in this stored procedure. When I run this stored procedure, I see the output I expect to see. I notice that it returns and integer. Is that cause for concern? Also, when I try to report against the output of this data and use any aggregates other than FIRST, I cannot get any of the aggregates to function.

What am I doing wrong or is the stored procedure correct?

```
USE [SPCPRD]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spReportPlantLineWeightEvaluation_Gainseeker]    Script Date: 1/3/2019 8:26:19 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReportPlantLineWeightEvaluation_Gainseeker]
(
    @PlantCode char(30), -- '1002'
    @MachineLineID char(30), -- 'ND'
    @StartDate char(30), -- = '08/05/2018 00:00:00';
    @EndDate char(30), -- = '09/05/2018 23:59:59';
    @ProductCode char(30) -- = '20J16HD'
)

AS
BEGIN

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---- Create a CTE to hold the analysis data
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        CREATE TABLE #AnalysisData
    (
        PLANT_CODE CHAR(30),
        ITEM_CODE varchar(30), 
        SampleTime char(30),
        MachineID char(30),
        RowNum char(30),
        RowPos char(30),
        Cavity char(30),
        TestedBy char(30),
        [WEIGHT] float,
        AverageLineWeight DECIMAL(10,2),
        [THICKNESS SIDEWALL MIN] float,
        [THICKNESS SIDEWALL MAX] float,
        [OFF CENTER TOLERANCE] float,
        [THICKNESS BOTTOM] float,
    );

    WITH FirstData AS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT        OC_VDATA.UDL1 AS PLANT_CODE, dbo.fnItemCodeFromPartNo(LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12)) AS ITEM_CODE, 
                                     OC_VDATA.UDL5 AS TestName, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40 AS SampleTime, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL8 AS MachineID, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL13 AS RowNum, 
                                     OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL21 AS RowPos, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL12 AS Cavity, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL18 AS TestedBy, OC_VDATA.DATA1
            FROM            OC_VDAT_AUX INNER JOIN
                                     OC_VDATA ON OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX = OC_VDATA.PARTNO AND OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX = OC_VDATA.DATETIME
            WHERE        (OC_VDATA.UDL1 = @PlantCode) AND (OC_VDATA.UDL5 IN ('WEIGHT', 'THICKNESS BOTTOM', 'OFF CENTER TOLERANCE')) AND (OC_VDATA.UDL6 = @MachineLineID)
                             AND (OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate, 102))
                             AND (dbo.fnItemCodeFromPartNo(LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12)) = @ProductCode)
        ) AS BaseData1
        PIVOT (Min(Data1) FOR TestName IN([WEIGHT],[THICKNESS BOTTOM],[OFF CENTER TOLERANCE])) as pvt
    ),

    SecondData AS
    (
        SELECT        OC_VDATA.UDL1 AS PLANT_CODE, dbo.fnItemCodeFromPartNo(LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12)) AS ITEM_CODE, 
                                 OC_VDATA.UDL5 AS TestName, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40 AS SampleTime, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL8 AS MachineID, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL13 AS RowNum, 
                                 OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL21 AS RowPos, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL12 AS Cavity, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL18 AS TestedBy,
                                 OC_VDATA.DATA1 AS 'THICKNESS SIDEWALL MIN', OC_VDATA.DATA2 AS 'THICKNESS SIDEWALL MAX'
        FROM            OC_VDAT_AUX INNER JOIN
                                 OC_VDATA ON OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX = OC_VDATA.PARTNO AND OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX = OC_VDATA.DATETIME
        WHERE        (OC_VDATA.UDL1 = @PlantCode) AND (OC_VDATA.UDL5  = 'THICKNESS SIDEWALL') AND 
                                 (OC_VDATA.UDL6 = @MachineLineID) AND (OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate, 102))
                                 AND (dbo.fnItemCodeFromPartNo(LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12)) = @ProductCode)
    ),

    LineWeight AS
    (
        SELECT        OC_VDATA.UDL1 AS PLANT_CODE, dbo.fnItemCodeFromPartNo(LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12)) AS ITEM_CODE, Cast(Avg(OC_VDATA.DATA1) AS decimal(10,2)) as AverageLineWeight
        FROM            OC_VDAT_AUX INNER JOIN
                                 OC_VDATA ON OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX = OC_VDATA.PARTNO AND OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX = OC_VDATA.DATETIME
        WHERE        (OC_VDATA.UDL1 = @PlantCode) AND (OC_VDATA.UDL5 = 'WEIGHT') AND (OC_VDATA.UDL6 = @MachineLineID) AND (OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40 BETWEEN 
                                 CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate, 102)) AND (dbo.fnItemCodeFromPartNo(LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12)) 
                                 = @ProductCode)
        GROUP BY  OC_VDATA.UDL1, dbo.fnItemCodeFromPartNo(LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12))
    )

    INSERT INTO #AnalysisData
        SELECT f.PLANT_CODE, f.ITEM_CODE, f.SampleTime, f.MachineID, f.RowNum, f.RowPos, f.Cavity, f.TestedBy, f.WEIGHT, lw.AverageLineWeight,
            s.[THICKNESS SIDEWALL MIN], s.[THICKNESS SIDEWALL MAX], f.[OFF CENTER TOLERANCE], f.[THICKNESS BOTTOM]
        FROM FirstData AS f INNER JOIN 
            SecondData AS s ON f.PLANT_CODE = s.PLANT_CODE INNER JOIN LineWeight AS lw ON f.PLANT_CODE = lw.PLANT_CODE
                AND f.ITEM_CODE = s.ITEM_CODE
                AND f.SampleTime = s.SampleTime
                AND f.MachineID = s.MachineID
                AND f.RowNum = s.RowNum
                AND f.RowPos = s.RowPos
                AND f.Cavity = s.Cavity
                AND f.TestedBy = s.TestedBy

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Create a CTE to hold the spec data
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE #SpecDataFinal
    (
        PLANT_CODE CHAR(30),
        ITEM_CODE varchar(30),
        [Weight - LowerSpec] float,
        [Weight - Target] float,
        [Weight - UpperSpec] float,
        [Thickness Sidewall - LowerSpec] float,
        [Thickness Sidewall - Target] float,
        [Thickness Sidewall - UpperSpec] float,
        [Thickness Bottom - LowerSpec] float,
        [Thickness Bottom - Target] float,
        [Thickness Bottom - UpperSpec] float,
        [Off Center Tolerance - LowerSpec] float,
        [Off Center Tolerance - Target] float,
        [Off Center Tolerance - UpperSpec] float
    );

    WITH SpecDataMod AS
    (
        SELECT PLANT_CODE, ITEM_CODE, PROPERTY + ' - ' + SpecType AS PropertyType, SpecValue FROM
        (
            SELECT PLANT_CODE, PARTNO, ITEM_CODE, PROPERTY, v.*
            FROM vwSpecsByPlantCode 
            CROSS APPLY (values ('LowerSpec', INDLS), ('Target', TARGETX), ('UpperSpec', INDUS)) v(SpecType, SpecValue)
        ) AS SpecData
    )

    INSERT INTO #SpecDataFinal
        SELECT * FROM(SELECT PLANT_CODE, ITEM_CODE, PropertyType, SpecValue FROM SpecDataMod) AS SpecBaseData
        PIVOT (Min(SpecValue) FOR PropertyType IN([Weight - LowerSpec],[Weight - Target],[Weight - UpperSpec],[Thickness Sidewall - LowerSpec]
            ,[Thickness Sidewall - Target],[Thickness Sidewall - UpperSpec],[Thickness Bottom - LowerSpec],[Thickness Bottom - Target]
            ,[Thickness Bottom - UpperSpec],[Off Center Tolerance - LowerSpec],[Off Center Tolerance - Target],[Off Center Tolerance - UpperSpec])) as pvt

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Finally, merge the data together
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SELECT  RTRIM(ad.PLANT_CODE) AS PLANT_CODE, RTRIM(ad.ITEM_CODE) AS ITEM_CODE, RTRIM(ad.SampleTime) AS SampleTime, RTRIM(ad.MachineID) as MachineID, 
        RTRIM(ad.RowNum) as RowNum, RTRIM(ad.RowPos) as RowPos, RTRIM(ad.Cavity) as Cavity, RTRIM(ad.TestedBy) AS TestedBy, RTRIM(ad.WEIGHT) as WEIGHT,
        RTRIM(ad.AverageLineWeight) AS AverageLineWeight, RTRIM(ad.[THICKNESS SIDEWALL MIN]) AS [THICKNESS SIDEWALL MIN], 
        rtrim(ad.[THICKNESS SIDEWALL MAX]) as [THICKNESS SIDEWALL MAX], rtrim(ad.[OFF CENTER TOLERANCE]) as [OFF CENTER TOLERANCE], 
        rtrim(ad.[THICKNESS BOTTOM]) as [THICKNESS BOTTOM], rtrim(sd.[Weight - LowerSpec]) as [Weight - LowerSpec], rtrim(sd.[Weight - Target]) as [Weight - Target],
        rtrim(sd.[Weight - UpperSpec]) as [Weight - UpperSpec], rtrim(sd.[Thickness Sidewall - LowerSpec]) as [Thickness Sidewall - LowerSpec], 
        rtrim(sd.[Thickness Sidewall - Target]) AS [Thickness Sidewall - Target] , rtrim(sd.[Thickness Sidewall - UpperSpec]) as [Thickness Sidewall - UpperSpec],
        rtrim(sd.[Thickness Bottom - LowerSpec]) as [Thickness Bottom - LowerSpec], rtrim(sd.[Thickness Bottom - Target]) as [Thickness Bottom - Target], 
        rtrim(sd.[Thickness Bottom - UpperSpec]) AS [Thickness Bottom - UpperSpec], rtrim(sd.[Off Center Tolerance - LowerSpec]) as [Off Center Tolerance - LowerSpec], 
        rtrim(sd.[Off Center Tolerance - Target]) as [Off Center Tolerance - Target], rtrim(sd.[Off Center Tolerance - UpperSpec]) as [Off Center Tolerance - UpperSpec]
    FROM #AnalysisData as ad INNER JOIN #SpecDataFinal AS sd ON ad.ITEM_CODE = sd.ITEM_CODE AND ad.PLANT_CODE = sd.PLANT_CODE
    ORDER BY RowPos

    --SELECT * 
    --FROM #AnalysisData as ad INNER JOIN #SpecDataFinal AS sd ON ad.ITEM_CODE = sd.ITEM_CODE AND ad.PLANT_CODE = sd.PLANT_CODE
    --ORDER BY ad.SampleTime, ad.RowNum, ad.RowPos

    DROP TABLE #SpecDataFinal
    DROP TABLE #AnalysisData

END
```

I can see my results as I expect to see them. When I put the dataset into SSRS and I want to use any of the aggregates, I can only see the FIRST aggregate when I run my report. If I use any of the others, like MIN, MAX, AVG, etc, and run my report, I don't see any of the other aggregates show in my report. It's just a blank spot in the report. Long story short, I was wondering if my stored procedure had anything to do with any of the other aggregates not being able to run.

Comment: When have you add the code in the dataset in SSRS, Does it returns more data than the first row?

Comment: You said *When I run this stored procedure, I see the output I expect to see*. So what's the question? *I notice that it returns and integer*. Do you mean when you call it from an application? If so, this means success.

Comment: Geovanny - Yes, I can see my results as I expect to see them. When I put the dataset into SSRS and I want to use any of the aggregates, I can only see the FIRST aggregate when I run my report. If I use any of the others, like MIN, MAX, AVG, etc, and run my report, I don't see any of the other aggregates show in my report. It's just a blank spot in the report. Long story short, I was wondering if my stored procedure had anything to do with any of the other aggregates not being able to run.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run this stored procedure, I see the output I expect to see.

This means the stored procedure is working fine.   If you aren't seeing the results in the SSRS, then the problem is in the SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, so here it goes.

First, you need some serious code reviewing. This is not the place for that. A good set of reviewers will offer useful comments about improving your code, improving your skills, making your code more efficient, etc.

Simple things like STOP USING RTRIM with float datatypes (e.g., rtrim(sd.[Off Center Tolerance - Target] ). Why do you do that? That column is defined as float. You trim PlantCode everywhere. Why? You defined it as char(30) everywhere in your code - what is the actual datatype in your schema? If it has variable length, then use varchar (especially in your parameter).

Why do you pass datetime values as strings for parameters? And you make another typical mistake - 23:59:59 is not the largest possible time component for datetime or datetime2. Don't use an inclusive upper boundary - use an exclusive upper boundary to avoid this sort of thing. BTW it might be that your forced implicit conversion of your float columns to string is the source of your problem.

Next - add "set nocount on" as the first statement to every stored procedure and trigger you write. This avoids sending the "x rows affected" message to the application executing this logic.

Try adding some useful comments for whoever must support this code. And make certain they are both accurate and useful. You have "create a cte to hold ..." in multiple places. First, no one generally cares how you generate the required information. Next, you are using CTEs to populate a temp table that you create. "Create" typically applies to objects that get created and it is unusual to use that term with a CTE. In fact, you use many CTEs rather than the one (singular) implied in your comment.

There are other things that a good code review should find - some best practices included.

Answer (score -1):

Try cast or convert for your operations. It might work

Comment: This is not the sort of thing that goes in an answer. In future please put it as a comment or have a more comprehensive answer

Comment: Well i was not aware of protocol but will do